# Login with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am trying to login in the website below to download a file, but I keep getting this message:
"SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"

The script I am developing is in the server using Apache and PHP 5.3.

```
<?
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password!';
$loginUrl = 'https://www.orangefl.realtaxlien.com';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'loginName='.$username.'&password='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate and check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Here is how your code should be :

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$loginUrl = 'https://www.orangefl.realtaxlien.com/index.cfm?folder=home';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

$var = array(
    'loginName' => trim($username),
    'password' => trim($password),
    'vendorID' => '12095',
    'loginFormAction' => 'index.cfm?folder=home',
    'loginAction' => 'login',
    'folder' => 'login');

$post_array = array();
    foreach ($var as $key => $value)
    {
        $post_array[] = urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
    }
$post_string = implode('&', $post_array);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$store = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Worked like a charmed. Thank you sir.

Comment: Hi, even when the error is gone, I am still unable to login in the site. Do you see anything wrong with the login procedure of the script?